# Send WAV files though http retrofit2 requests - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, httprequest, retrofit2, wav

I'm running a Machine Learning model on a server that works with WAV files. Can I send WAV files stored in mobile phone through HTTP requests with Android Studio, in WAV form?

So far I'm making (get) requests using retrofit2 like this:

MainActivity.java:

```
private void getbuttonclicked() {
    Call call = RequestManager.INSTANCE.getService().getChords();
    call.enqueue((Callback)(new Callback() {public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(call, "call");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(response, "response");
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_text)).setText("REQUEST OK");
        }
    }
```

DataManager.kt:

```
object RequestManager {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()


    init {
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myip/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)

}
```

Api.kt:

```
interface Api {
    @GET(".")
    fun getChords(): Call<chord_model>
}
```

chord_model.java:

```
public class chord_model {
    @SerializedName("Chords")
    @Expose
    private List<String> chords = null;
    @SerializedName("Bass")
    @Expose
    private List<String> bass = null;

    public List<String> getChords() {
        return chords;
    }

    public void setChords(List<String> chords) {
        this.chords = chords;
    }

    public List<String> getBass() {
        return bass;
    }

    public void setBass(List<String> bass) {
        this.bass = bass;
    }

}
```

I suppose I'll have to use post requests, but how do I send a whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-to-server-using-retrofit-2-in-android/

Basically you'll be sending a POST request. Using postman,it would be something like this:
[image]